# Running onto the Online compiler but giving seg fault on terminal(Ubuntu)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, ubuntu-14.04

My program compiled successfully but it gave me segmentation fault when i ran this code on linux system but when i executed the same code on the online compiler Ideone it gave me correct output. Below is the code.

**Why is this so can any one explain and if anything is wrong in code than also please suggest the correct solution.


Thanks**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MAX_SIZE=21;

struct node;
typedef struct node NODE;
typedef NODE *link;

struct node{
   int data;
   link next;
};

typedef struct{
   link head;
   int top;
}Stack;

Stack createStack(Stack s){
   s.head = NULL;
   s.top = 0;
   return s;
}

link createNode(link n,int data){
   n = (link)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   n->data = data;
   n->next = NULL;
   return n;
}

Stack push(Stack s,int data){
   if(s.top < MAX_SIZE){
      link newNode = createNode(newNode,data);    
      if(s.head == NULL){
         s.head = newNode;
      }else{
         newNode->next = s.head;
         s.head = newNode;
      }
      s.top++;
   }else{
      printf("Overflow\n");
   }

   return s;
}

Stack pop(Stack s){
   link temp = s.head; 
   if(s.top == 0){
      printf("Underflow\n");
   }else{
      s.head = s.head->next;
      s.top--;
      free(temp);
   }
   return s;
}

void printStack(Stack s){
   link temp = s.head;
   while(temp->next){
      printf("%d -> ",temp->data);
      temp = temp->next;
   }
   printf("%d\n",temp->data);
}

int main(void){
   Stack s;
   s = push(s,5);
   s = push(s,7);
   s = push(s,9);
   s = push(s,11);
   printf("%d\t",s.top);
   printf("%d",s.head->next->next->data);
   printStack(s);
   s = pop(s);
   printStack(s);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but in `createNode(link n, ...)` you never do anything with the `n` the caller provides... so get rid of it as a parameter completely.

Comment: Also, your `push()` function does not modify the `s` parameter it receives, so `s = push(s, ...);` has no reason to use any return value. Make the function `void`.

Comment: Probably the cause of your issue: undefined behavior. You have not initialized `Stack s` prior to using it, so it starts out with garbage data. I'll bet you intended to use that poorly written `createStack()` function. (Poorly written because, like `push()` and `pop()`, it has a useless return value.)

Comment: 1) Do not `typedef` pointers! That obfuscates the semantics, results in confusion and inhibits certain uses. 2) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  (I also use `-Wconversion -std=c99`)  Which would tell you about the usage of uninitialized variable(s) problem in the code.

Comment: *My program compiled successfully*  Well, no it does not.   and after fixing the compiler/syntax statements, the logic has a few problems.  Stepping through the code with a debugger (like gdb) and carefully watching the pointer value changes would expose some of the logic problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @mah is on the spot.

> You have not initialized `Stack s` prior to using it, so it starts out with garbage data.

That leads to undefined behavior.

After the line

```
Stack s;
```

add

```
s = createStack(s);
```

Also, in `push`, replace

```
link newNode = createNode(newNode,data);
```

by

```
link newNode = NULL;
newNode = createNode(newNode,data);
```

My compiler complains about using uninitialized value of `newNode` in the call.